# jQuery mobile - Splitting up pages to different files

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile

I am developing a web app based on jQuery and jQuery mobile. I want to show different pages, but since the corresponding html-markup might become quite large I would like to split up the html into different files, i.e.:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />            
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/jquery.mobile-1.4.3.min.css" />            
        <title>Hello World</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div data-role="page" id="page1">
          <!-- import markup for page1 here -->
        </div>

        <div data-role="page" id="page2">
          <!-- import markup for page2 here -->
        </div>

        <script src="js/libs/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/libs/jquery.mobile-1.4.3.min.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

What can I do to import my markup where it says `<!-- import markup for page<x> -->`? Is there any way to achieve that?

I tried using `<script>$("#page1").load("page1.html");</script>` but this messes the entire page up! Since the web app should be packed as a native app for smartphones later php is not an option.

Comment: If you load an external page, jQM will fetch first page div only. `.load()` isn't meant to be used in jQM, instead, use `.pagecontainer("load", "page.html")` if you're using jQM 1.4

Comment: Does pagecontainer("load", "page.html") replace the entire `<div data-role="page">`-segment? Or does it have to be inside (as in my question above)?

Comment: No, it doesn't replace any page, it inserts a page into DOM. http://jqmtricks.wordpress.com/2014/05/23/jquery-mobile-page-events-extra/

Comment: I simply cannot get it to work. Would you mind to please post a working example as an answer? I'm not quite sure were to put the pagecontainer-method (inside or outside a div) etc.

Comment: ... And I can't find a good example via google either

Comment: Okay, I was able to add the pages to the dom, but now there is a followup-question. Please see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25301621/jquery-mobile-pagecontainer-disappears-from-dom

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to Omar's comments above and his answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25301621/jquery-mobile-pagecontainer-disappears-from-dom) I was able to come up with a working solution.

1.) Add external pages to the DOM by using `$.mobile.pageContainer.pagecontainer("load", "<externalResName>.html");`

2.) Navigate to the newly loaded page by adding a listener to the document (i.e. `$(document).on( "pagecontainerload", function( event, ui ) { //... } );`)

3.) Make sure that the external ressource stays in the DOM by adding `data-dom-cache="true"` to the page's `div`-tag.

**test.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />        
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.3/jquery.mobile-1.4.3.min.css" />
        <title>Hello jqm</title>
    </head>
    <body>  
      <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
      <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.3/jquery.mobile-1.4.3.min.js"></script>

      <script> 
        $(document).ready(function(){   
          $(document).on( "pagecontainerload", function( event, ui ) {
            console.log('navigating to page1...');
            $.mobile.pageContainer.pagecontainer("change", "#page1");
            console.log('navigating done!');          
          } );

          console.log('loading pagecontainers...');
          $.mobile.pageContainer.pagecontainer("load", "page1.html");
          $.mobile.pageContainer.pagecontainer("load", "page2.html");
          console.log('pagecontainer-load done!');
        });
      </script>    
    </body>
</html>
```

**page1.html**

```
<div data-role="page" id="page1" data-dom-cache="true">
  <div data-role="header">
    <h1>Page 1</h1>
  </div>
  <div role="main" class="ui-content">
    <a href="#page2" data-transition="slide" class="ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-btn-inline">Go To Page 2</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

**page2.html**

```
<div data-role="page" id="page2" data-dom-cache="true">
  <div data-role="header">
    <h1>Page 2</h1>
  </div>
  <div role="main" class="ui-content">
    <a href="#page1" data-rel="back" data-transition="slide" class="ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-btn-inline">Go Back To Page 1</a>
  </div>
</div>
```