# jQuery mobile - Pagecontainer disappears from DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile, dom

In jQuery mobile I want to load pagecontainers from external files. I can add the markup to my DOM, but the problem I am facing afterwards is that as soon as I navigate to #page2, the entire #page1-div disappears from the DOM and thus I cannot navigate back (Please see screenshots below).

**DOM before clicking "Go To Page 2"**

[image: before]

**DOM after clicking "Go To Page 2"**

[image: after]

As you can see, the entire #page1-div is gone for good. Why is that? Any thoughts? Please see my markup and code below:

**test.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />        
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.3/jquery.mobile-1.4.3.min.css" />
        <title>Hello jqm</title>
    </head>
    <body>  
      <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
      <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.3/jquery.mobile-1.4.3.min.js"></script>

      <script> 
        $(document).ready(function(){   
          $(document).on( "pagecontainerload", function( event, ui ) {
            console.log('navigating to page1...');
            $.mobile.pageContainer.pagecontainer("change", "#page1");
            console.log('navigating done!');          
          } );

          console.log('loading pagecontainers...');
          $.mobile.pageContainer.pagecontainer("load", "page1.html");
          $.mobile.pageContainer.pagecontainer("load", "page2.html");
          console.log('pagecontainer-load done!');
        });
      </script>    
    </body>
</html>
```

**page1.html**

```
<div data-role="page" id="page1">
  <div data-role="header">
    <h1>Page 1</h1>
  </div>
  <div role="main" class="ui-content">
    <a href="#page2" data-transition="slide" class="ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-btn-inline">Go To Page 2</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

**page2.html**

```
<div data-role="page" id="page2" class="page2">
  <div data-role="header">
    <h1>Page 2</h1>
  </div>
  <div role="main" class="ui-content">
    <a href="#page1" data-rel="back" data-transition="slide" class="ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-btn-inline">Go Back To Page 1</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

*Remarks: This is a follow up question to this one: [jQuery mobile - Splitting up pages to different files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25265336/jquery-mobile-splitting-up-pages-to-different-files)*

Comment: Would you mind creating a fiddle for better understanding?

Comment: I'd love to, but jsfiddle seems not to work with those imports (at least I cannot get it to work when hosting page1.html and page2.html publically in my dropbox). However, I replaced all external links in the markup above to link public cdns, thus you can simply copy and paste the code to three local files on your hdd and open test.html to see the results in your browser.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

jQuery Mobile removes external pages when you navigate away of them. You should leave a base page cached in DOM rather than loading all pages.

- Solution one: in test.html, add html markup of page1.html and load page2.html externally.
- Solution two: add `data-dom-cache="true"` to page1 div to keep it cached even if it's loaded externally.

  ```
    <div data-role="page" id="page1" data-dom-cache="true">
  ```

---

### Update

You can cache all external pages at once without the need to add `data-dom-cache` to each and every page div. All you need to do is to globally set `domCache` option of page widget to `true` on `mobileinit` event. The code should be placed after jQuery.js and before jQuery-Mobile.js.

```
<script src="jquery.js" />
<script>
   $(document).on("mobileinit", function () {
      $.mobile.page.prototype.options.domCache = true;
   });
</script>
<script src="jquery-mobile.js" />
```

Comment: dude, you are a life saver! thanks, that works!!! any downsides on using `data-dom-cache="true"` on every page? I have four or five of them in my app?

Comment: You're welcome :) you don't have to cache them all. Only base page in case it's not static.

Comment: @Christian Check the updated answer, you dont need to add `data-dom-cache` to all pages.

Answer (score 0):

For this case, you should try to init the page manually

In page1:

```
$(document).bind("mobileinit", function () {
    ...
    $.mobile.autoInitializePage = false;
    $.mobile.initializePage();
});
```

In page2:

```
$(function () {
    $.mobile.activePage = null;
    $.mobile.initializePage();
});
```

This is my solution for switch 2 pages not in same HTML.

Comment: Still the same problem... I put the code you gave me in a <script>-block inside each file (page1.html and page2.html). #page1-div keeps disappearing :-( Could you post the entire code you are suggesting?